# Ephesoft cann't Access (Requested resource not available)?

Tags: apache, tomcat, service-not-available

I installed Ephesoft Enterprise Edition (Ephesoft_3.0.3.4_SP2) Trail 30 days. When I start Ephesoft Server and when I try and run the admin module or ephesoft I get the following response: "HTTP - Requested resource not available...Apache/Tomcat 6.0.26

The log is here:

```
2013-10-27 12:52:12,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-10-27 12:52:12,027 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol- Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2013-10-27 12:52:13,028 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Stopping service Catalina
2013-10-27 12:52:13,237 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext- Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dcma] has not been started
2013-10-27 12:52:13,243 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-10-27 12:52:13,280 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol- Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2013-10-27 12:52:36,091 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
2013-10-27 12:52:36,092 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2013-10-27 12:52:36,273 [main] WARN  org.apache.commons.digester.Digester- [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '10' did not find a matching property.
2013-10-27 12:52:36,999 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-10-27 12:52:37,000 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol- Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2013-10-27 12:52:37,000 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Initialization processed in 1532 ms
2013-10-27 12:52:37,050 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Starting service Catalina
2013-10-27 12:52:37,051 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine- Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
2013-10-27 12:53:39,375 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
2013-10-27 12:53:39,377 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2013-10-27 12:53:39,630 [main] WARN  org.apache.commons.digester.Digester- [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '10' did not find a matching property.
2013-10-27 12:53:40,598 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-10-27 12:53:40,599 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol- Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2013-10-27 12:53:40,599 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Initialization processed in 1968 ms
2013-10-27 12:53:40,668 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Starting service Catalina
2013-10-27 12:53:40,669 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine- Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
2013-10-27 12:54:33,515 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dcma]- Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseServer' defined in class path resource [META-INF/applicationContext-license-server.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ephesoft.license.server.LicenseServerManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is ag: There is no license certificate installed for Ephesoft Document Capture and Mail room automation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ephesoft.license.server.LicenseServerManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is ag: There is no license certificate installed for Ephesoft Document Capture and Mail room automation.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: ag: There is no license certificate installed for Ephesoft Document Capture and Mail room automation.
    at z.a(Unknown Source)
    at z.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.ephesoft.license.server.LicenseServerManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 30 more
2013-10-27 12:54:33,521 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext- Error listenerStart
2013-10-27 12:54:33,521 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext- Context [/dcma] startup failed due to previous errors
2013-10-27 12:54:33,531 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,532 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,532 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,532 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,533 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,534 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,534 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,535 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,535 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,536 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,536 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,536 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,536 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,537 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,538 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,538 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,539 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,543 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,543 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,544 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,544 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a TimerThread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] via the java.util.Timer API but has failed to stop it. To prevent a memory leak, the timer (and hence the associated thread) has been forcibly cancelled. 
2013-10-27 12:54:33,545 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [Replication Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,545 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,546 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,546 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,547 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,547 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,548 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,548 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,549 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,550 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,550 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,551 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [DispatcherThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,551 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,551 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,552 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,552 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,552 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,552 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,553 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,553 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,553 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,554 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,555 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,555 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,555 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,555 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,556 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,556 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,556 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,557 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,557 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,557 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#2_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,557 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,558 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,558 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,558 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,558 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,558 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,559 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,559 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,559 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,559 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,559 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,561 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,562 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,562 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:33,562 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2013-10-27 12:54:34,076 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
2013-10-27 12:54:34,109 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
2013-10-27 12:54:34,142 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application directory docs
2013-10-27 12:54:34,165 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application directory examples
2013-10-27 12:54:34,300 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application directory ROOT
2013-10-27 12:54:34,330 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-10-27 12:54:34,343 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol- Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2013-10-27 12:54:34,346 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in 53745 ms
```

Please, any Help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the most important line in the error log:

```
Error creating bean with name 'licenseServer' defined in class path resource 
    [META-INF/applicationContext-license-server.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed
```

So if your trial version has a trial license, you probably have to install that first.

Do a search in the above XML and search for "licenseServer". Maybe it gives some hints on what to do.

Comment: good answer, I wanna make sure from it before I mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a license issue. After doing any Ephesoft Enterprise installation you have to email them your **details.properties** file which is located located in Ephesoft\Dependencies\licensing.

They will provide you with a 30day license which you will install on your server.When they send you the license file they will also provide you with instructions of how to install the license.

http://www.ephesoft.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_To?#How_to_install_the_Ephesoft_Enterprise_license